# Spring data mongodb - The 'cursor' option is required

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to execute an aggregate operation using Spring Data MongoDB 3.6-rc4.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    lookup("orders", "orderId", "_id", "order") 
);
List<BasicDBObject> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, "transactions", BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
```

But get the following error on running the query

```
2017-11-24 17:03:41,539 WARN  org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate : Command execution of { "aggregate" : "transactions" , "pipeline" : [ { "$lookup" : { "from" : "orders" , "localField" : "orderId" , "foreignField" : "_id" , "as" : "order"}}]} failed: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
2017-11-24 17:03:41,574 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Command execution failed:  Error [The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument], Command = { "aggregate" : "transactions" , "pipeline" : [ { "$lookup" : { "from" : "orders" , "localField" : "orderId" , "foreignField" : "_id" , "as" : "order"}}]}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }] with root cause
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:80) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:94) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.handleCommandError(MongoTemplate.java:2100) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1577) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1505) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.10.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: Mongo DB version is v3.6.0-rc4

Answer (score 25, accepted):

MongoDB changed in 3.6 how the aggregation command works. Aggregations require now a cursor. We [adapted Spring Data MongoDB 2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/515) but not previous versions.

Aggregations must be invoked through the collection's `aggregate(…)` method instead of calling the command directly. This is also the reason why we didn't backport the change. `executeCommand(…)` is no longer called and we don't want to break compatibility in a bugfix release.

The easiest approach for you can be to override the `aggregate(…)` method and call the appropriate method, `DBCollection.aggregate(…)` with the mapped aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Is MongoDB 3.4 compatible with current version of spring data, and supports aggregates ?

Comment: Yes, it is fully supported.

Comment: Hi, guys. Recently faced with the same problem. As far I understand I should do one of the following: a) waiting for release of Spring Data MongoDB 2.1, b) create my own class inherited from MongoTemplate, and override aggregate() method by introducing all changes contained in PR https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/515.
Am I right?

Comment: A fixed Spring Data release is available as of today.

Comment: @mp911de, thank you for the fast reply. But there is another one problem :) I'm using spring-data-mongodb through spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb which is currently coupled with spring-data-mongodb v1.10.9. BTW, I don't see v2.1.0 in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb-parent. Thank you again.

Comment: hello @mp911de could you show an example using dbcollection .aggregate? I tried to updated spring-data, but doesn't up the application, we need update spring-boot-2 and I have other libs which are not yet supported (apache-camel)

Answer (score 11):

I was using:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
```

Then after upgraded my dependency to a higher version, the issue was resolved:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: MongoDB 3.6 requires spring 1.5.10.RELEASE for aggregation operations

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading the spring boot version didn't work for me. Changing outputmode as cursor as providing a cursor is mandatory, worked. Verified in mongo 3.6

```
List<DBObject> list = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
list.add(unwind.toDBObject(Aggregation.DEFAULT_CONTEXT));
list.add(group.toDBObject(Aggregation.DEFAULT_CONTEXT));
list.add(sort.toDBObject(Aggregation.DEFAULT_CONTEXT));

DBCollection col = mongoTemplate.getCollection("users");

Cursor cursor = col.aggregate(list, AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(true).outputMode(OutputMode.CURSOR).build());

List<AggregationResultVO> result = new ArrayList<AggregationResultVO>();

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
     DBObject object = cursor.next();
     result.add(new AggregationResultVO(object.get("aggregationResultId").toString()));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems Pull Request mentionned by @mp911de has been release in version 1.10.10 of Spring Data MongoDB. 
So you can either

- upgrade your Spring Data MongoDB dependency to 1.10.10.RELEASE
- upgrade your spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency to 1.5.10.RELEASE

Comment: This exact two bullets worked for me. Thanks @Atari

Answer (score 2):

You can use cursor option available with aggregate query pipeline.

```
{cursor: { batchSize: batch_size }}
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

`Aggregation.newAggregation(AggregationOperation... operations).withOptions(new AggregationOptions(false,false,new Document().append("batchSize" , batch_size)))` may help in this case

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this type of error when using Mongodb version 3.6.2.

Check your version of ***org.springframework.data*** in pom.xml

For me, i have changed **org.springframework.data** version to 2.0.3.RELEASE and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
Just updating the spring boot version works for me.
This is the version that I have used and worked....
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

Comment: We have upgraded MongoDB from 3.4 to 5.0, Faced the same issue. But this verison change solved the issue. Thanks a lot for the solution you saved my day with lots of code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this type of error when using org.springframework.data version 1.10.3.RELEASE. And then i have changed  version to 2.0.5.RELEASE and my problem was solved.

Comment: could be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by upgrading spring boot to the '2.1.3.RELEASE' version.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <!--<version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>-->
        <relativePath></relativePath>
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue and you are using Studio 3T, there is an option in the Options tab, just check it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your command no longer works due to a change in mongodb driver change in version `3.6`.
You need to invoke it from `dbCollection.aggregate(...)` method instead.

Comment: could be a comment

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all above (short of changing the code to using a cursor) to no avail.

In the end, I had to upgrage

```
'mongo-java-driver'       : '3.6.2'
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Spring Boot 2.0.0 or later.
2. Add `AggregationOptions` with cursor to your `Aggregation`:

```java
AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = AggregationOptions.builder()
    .allowDiskUse(true)
    .cursor(new Document())
    .build();
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(aggregationOperations)
    .withOptions(aggregationOptions);
```

3. Call `aggregateStream()` (not `aggregate()`) method of `MongoOperations`. This method utilizes the cursor responded by MongoDB:

```java
mongoOps.aggregateStream(aggregation, "collection", MyEntity.class)
```