# Error in MongoDB while displaying data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

> 2018-01-11 10:34:57 ERROR ConsumerLoadDAOImpl:357 -
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Command
>   execution failed:  Error [The 'cursor' option is required, except for
>   aggregate with the explain argument],

Command =

```
{  
   "aggregate":"Product",
   "pipeline":[  
      {  
         "$group":{  
            "_id":"$productCode",
            "id":{  
               "$first":"$_id"
            },
            "productName":{  
               "$first":"$productName"
            },
            "description":{  
               "$first":"$description"
            },
            "productCode":{  
               "$first":"$productCode"
            },
            "eanCode":{  
               "$first":"$eanCode"
            },
            "categoryId":{  
               "$first":"$categoryId"
            },
            "subcategoryId":{  
               "$first":"$subcategoryId"
            },
            "productLineId":{  
               "$first":"$productLineId"
            },
            "brandId":{  
               "$first":"$brandId"
            },
            "mrp":{  
               "$first":"$mrp"
            },
            "discountedPrice":{  
               "$first":"$discountedPrice"
            },
            "consumerId":{  
               "$first":"$consumerId"
            },
            "status":{  
               "$first":"$status"
            },
            "createdDateTime":{  
               "$first":"$createdDateTime"
            },
            "attachmentId":{  
               "$first":"$attachmentId"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
};
```

`nested exception is com.mongodb.CommandFailureException:`

```
{  
   "serverUsed":"localhost:27017",
   "ok":0.0,
   "errmsg":"The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument",
   "code":9,
   "codeName":"FailedToParse"
}
```

can anyone help I am getting these errors in console while calling controller to display data.

```
jdk = 1.8
mongodb = 3.6
spring = 4.x
```

Here is Controller code

```
public List<Product> searchProductWithAggregationWithPagination(Class<?> voName,String column,Integer currentPage,Integer noOfRecord) {

    List<Product> list1 = new ArrayList<Product>();
    try {
        GroupOperation groupByStateAndSumPop = group("productCode").
                first("id").as("id").
                first("productName").as("productName").
                first("description").as("description").
                first("productCode").as("productCode").
                first("eanCode").as("eanCode").
                first("categoryId").as("categoryId").
                first("subcategoryId").as("subcategoryId").
                first("productLineId").as("productLineId").
                first("brandId").as("brandId").
                first("mrp").as("mrp").
                first("discountedPrice").as("discountedPrice").
                first("consumerId").as("consumerId").
                first("status").as("status").
                first("createdDateTime").as("createdDateTime").
                first("attachmentId").as("attachmentId");

        MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("status").is(true));

        Aggregation agg = null;
        if(currentPage == 0 && noOfRecord == 0 && column.isEmpty()) {
            agg = newAggregation(groupByStateAndSumPop);
        }else {
            SortOperation sortByAvgPopAsc = sort(new Sort(Direction.DESC,column));
            agg = newAggregation(groupByStateAndSumPop
                    ,skip(currentPage),
                    limit(noOfRecord),matchStage,sortByAvgPopAsc);
        }

        AggregationResults<Product> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Product.class, Product.class);

        list1 = result.getMappedResults();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
    return list1;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring data mongodb - The 'cursor' option is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472688/spring-data-mongodb-the-cursor-option-is-required)

Comment: I already had seen that thread. thanks i am trying to check it with mongod 3.0 , and will update results ASAP.