# Is "spring-data-mongodb: 1.10.7" is compatible with "mongo v3.6.0"

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I am getting this exception, when I am using `mongoTemplate.aggregate` API.

> Command execution failed:  Error [The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument].

I am using sprig-data api version - 1.10.7. Is this version compatible with mongo v3.6.0 OR do i need to upgrade the spring-data API as well?

Comment: No, spring release version is compatible with 3.6. Spring mongo 2.x is compatible with 3.4. Your exception is related to change made in mongo 3.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring - mongodb - aggregation - The 'cursor' option is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490380/spring-mongodb-aggregation-the-cursor-option-is-required)

Answer (score 0):

Try using spring-data-mongodb:1.10.12