# spring data mongodb - aggregation with dates

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, aggregate

Following code doesn't give the expected results, i've tried with multiple documents, those documents structured as follows.

```
_id: 5a7714d44c75220958e6aa01
imei:355227045347655
point: [3.143453333333333,80.10954]
heading: 0
speed:0
timestamp: 2018-02-04 19:42:36.000
point_distance: 525.25
```

Now i need to calculate sum of `point_distance` of every record match with given `imei` and time period. I've tried to achieve this with following code but returns nothing even if required data exists.

```
public Object findDistance(long imei, Date from, Date to) {
    List aggregationOps = new ArrayList<>();
    //operations
    aggregationOps.add(match(Criteria.where("imei").is(imei)));
    aggregationOps.add(match(Criteria.where("timestamp").gte(from)));
    aggregationOps.add(match(Criteria.where("timestamp").lte(to)));
    aggregationOps.add(group("imei").sum("point_distance").as("distance"));
    aggregationOps.add(project("imei").and("distance").previousOperation());

    AggregationOptions agOps = new AggregationOptions.Builder().allowDiskUse(true).cursor(new BasicDBObject()).build();

    return (DistanceInfo) getMongoTemplate()
            .aggregate(newAggregation(aggregationOps).withOptions(agOps), Location.class, DistanceInfo.class)
            .getUniqueMappedResult();
}
```

`Date` > `from` and `to` are formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`

`DistanceInfo` class

```
public class DistanceInfo {
    long imei;
    double distance;
}
```

I'm new to this mongodb stuff and no idea what did i do wrong, how can i correct this ? any help is much appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't it be `lte(to)` ?

Comment: corrected, but still the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. this should work

```
MatchOperation matchOperation = match(Criteria.where("imei").is(imei) 
     .and("timestamp").gte(from.getTime()).lte(to.getTime()));

GroupOperation groupOperation = group("imei").sum("point_distance").as("distance");
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project().andExpression("imei").as("imei")
    .andExpression("distance").as("distance");

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(matchOperation, groupOperation, projectionOperation);
AggregationResults<DistanceInfo> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "location", DistanceInfo.class);

return  results.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: It returns an error `Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument'`

Comment: I'm using `mongodb-java-driver 3.6.1` and `spring-data-mongodb 1.10.9`

Comment: On my machine it works. I am using mongodb-driver 3.4.3 and spring-data-mongodb 1.10.8.RELEASE.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472688/spring-data-mongodb-the-cursor-option-is-required

Comment: Try removing `.cursor(new BasicDBObject())` this code in your originial code

Comment: so, i had to upgrade `spring-data` version to `1.10.10.RELEASE` and used this solution, it worked, removing `.cursor(new BasicDBObject())` didn't worked though, thank you for helping.