# how to resolve pentaho data integration error

Tags: kettle, pdi

I am using kettele tranformation with pdi I wrote the querys with mongodb my mongodb old version 3.4 kettele transformation is well working resently updating my mongodb version 3.6 ofter updating throw error

```
   - ERROR (version 8.0.0.0-28, build 8.0.0.0-28 from 2017-11-05 07.27.50 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2018/09/12 13:40:49 - MongoDB Input.0 - com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }
2018/09/12 13:40:49 - MongoDB Input.0 - Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }
2018/09/12 13:40:49 - MongoDB Input.0 - 
2018/09/12 13:40:49 - MongoDB Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.mongodbinput.MongoDbInput.processRow(MongoDbInput.java:137)
2018/09/12 13:40:49 - MongoDB Input.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
```

any one please suggest me.

Comment: well , this error comes from mongodb , not pentaho. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472688/spring-data-mongodb-the-cursor-option-is-required

Comment: recently i updated mongoDB version 3.6 if any updated version isssue ..@jipipayo Sep 12 at 15:14