# Mongodb inner join in java spring using AggregationOperation :Error [The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument]

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I am excecuting following mongodb query  I am new to mongo db ,please tell me what i am doing wrong

```
   db.entityCounter.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "fields",
         localField: "code",
         foreignField: "fieldCode",
         as: "fieldsresult"
       }
  },{
      $match:{
          $and: [{
              "fieldsresult.isVisible":"1"
              },{"type":"field"
                  }]
          }
          }])
```

below is java spring code

```
  LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
            .from("fields")
            .localField("code")
            .foreignField("fieldCode")
            .as("fieldsresult");

    AggregationOperation match1 = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("fieldsresult.isVisible").is("1"));

   // AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = Aggregation.newAggregationOptions();
    DBObject ob=new BasicDBObject();
    ((BasicDBObject) ob).put("batchSize",10);
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation,match1).withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().cursor(ob).build());



long val=0;
try {
    AggregationResults<EntityCounter> result = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, Fields.class, EntityCounter.class);
    // val= result.getMappedResults();
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

but I am getting  below error

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Command execution failed:  Error [The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument], Command = { "aggregate" : "entityCounter" , "pipeline" : [ { "$match" : { "fieldsresult.isVisible" : "1"}} , { "$lookup" : { "from" : "fields" , "localField" : "code" , "foreignField" : "fieldCode" , "as" : "fieldsresult"}}]}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }

Comment: whats the mongodb version you are using

Comment: and also the aggregate has several pipeline and you need to use match inside the aggragete not outside

Comment: Try using cursor option available with aggregation query pipeline : cursor: { batchSize: <int> }.. useful links : a) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47472688/spring-data-mongodb-the-cursor-option-is-required b) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: What is your spring mongo jar  version ? Do you have more code than what is posted ?

Comment: I have posted aggregation related code and issue is in above code only

Comment: I am using 3.4 version of mongodb

Comment: I need the spring mongo jar version not mongodb. You can find that inside your pom if you have one.

Comment: spring-data-mongodb  version is 1.8.2.RELEASE

Comment: Are you sure it is right version ? [Lookup support](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1326) was added in spring mongo from 1.9 version. Also I **cannot** reproduce the error with 1.9 or any other versions. Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? A github project will be helpful.

Comment: yes I am using right version

Comment: Its not possible. Lookup was only available from 1.9. So you can't use it when you are using 1.8. As advised please provide the complete example that can reproduce the error.

Answer (score -1):

The lookup was introduced in mongodb 3.4 please upgrade your dB

Comment: now i upgraded my version to  v4.0.2  then also i am getting same error

Comment: can you please share your mongodb debug log

Comment: vipul i have modified query but still getting error

Comment: its an issue in Spring framework if you are using spring-boot then please upgrade to 2.0
https://github.com/WoLpH/mongo-hacker/commit/5fdf310fae3ac7053e9e4e8a2ab88b42f2c68158
or use this 
AggregationOptions aggregationOptions=new AggregationOptions(false,false,200);
and add this option at last i.e Aggregation.newAggregation(match1, lookupOperation).withOptions(aggregationOptions);

Comment: i am not using spring boot

Comment: then use the second as described in above